# How to make domain name resolvable globally, not only within AWS' own dns-servers?

Tags: dns, amazon-web-services, nslookup

I want to publish my own dynamic website using aws. My setup so far:

- An AWS EC2-instance
- A dynamic IP linked to that instance
- A .de-domain name, that I registered using route 53
- A hosted zone in route 53 with an `A`-entry, linking my domain name to the dynamic IP

The setup looked promising, I can reach the server using its public IP-address.

If I do a namserver-lookup, using one of the four servers defined in the hosted zone's `NS`-entry, then the name can be correctly resolved:

```
#                      v-- one of the four servers in my NS-record
% nslookup mydomain.de ns-2018.awsdns-60.co.uk 
Server:     ns-2018.awsdns-60.co.uk
Address:    2600:9000:5307:e200::1#53

Name:    mydomain.de
Address: 18.157.136.93
#        ^-- perfect! This is my aws dynamic ip!
```

However normal lookups (and using the domain in my browser) fails:

```
#                      v-- no specific name server mentioned
% nslookup mydomain.de
;; Got SERVFAIL reply from 192.168.1.1, trying next server
Server:     fd00::de39:6fff:fe40:912d
Address:    fd00::de39:6fff:fe40:912d#53

** server can't find mydomain.de: SERVFAIL
```

Online nslookup-services also cannot resolve the name.

How can I register the domain at the public domain name servers, so that everyone can use the domain in the browser?

Comment: What does `dnstrace -s . mydomain.de` output? Does `whois` show Route53 as the registrar?

Comment: I used Route53 to register my domain today. Probably this makes it both: my registrar and nameserver host, right? @user1686

Comment: I suppose it does, though I haven't heard of Route53 offering both services previously. Either way, the NS entries within the zone don't really matter; what actually matters is the NS entries that the registrar uploads to the parent .de zone – if you registered it via Route53 they ought to do this correctly for their own nameservers, but can you check https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/domain-name-servers-glue-records.html#domain-name-servers-glue-records-adding-changing just in case?

Comment: whois.com lists four dns-servers, but different ones than aws route 53 shows. @user1686

Comment: I will try to update route-53's entries to match the whois data.

Comment: It seems like I can only update the entries (`NS`, `SOA`, etc.) of the hosted zone. The server-names in the hosted zone itself cannot be updated. I changed the values back to be consistent within route-53.

Comment: Maybe I have to wait two days, until the old record's TTL is due?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The names in the DNS-record, the hosted zone and the domain settings have to match.

You can change the DNS-record and the domain settings, but the servers in the hosted zone are fixed. Therefore the other two have to be changed.

1. Log in your **AWS console**
2. Navigate to Route 53, hosted zones, **your hosted zone**
3. Unfold the "Hosted zone details", copy the four names under the "**Name servers**" label
4. Make sure that the names in the **`NS`- and `SOA`-records** match - otherwise change them (this change will take usually 24 hours to be effective everywhere)
5. Navigate to Route 53, registered domains, **your domain**
6. Make sure that the names under the label "**Name servers**" match - otherwise change them (should only take some minutes/hours to be effective)

Answer (score 0):

Your config looks good. One advice though is to use an Elastic IP address, not a dynamic one, because if one day you restart (shutdown then restart), you will get a new dynamic IP address and you will have to ser the DNS entry again.

For your browser, DNS propagation can take up to 24 hours depending on your TTL.

Try also to flush your DNS cache.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I indeed am still hoping for the 24 hour delay to fix everything. Flushing my local DNS would only help, if online DNS-services can resolve the address correctly, right?

Comment: Yes. And I hope it all works now.

Comment: Sadly no, it does not yet work. The domain is `ffm-java-22-1.de` and I want it to be resolved to `18.157.136.93`. That only works if I manually choose `ns-2018.awsdns-60.co.uk` as name server :(

Comment: It resolves correctly to `18.157.136.93` for me.     Try nslookup ffm-java-22-1.de 8.8.8.8

Comment: Yes, it now works fine. The AWS-Support helped me. I posted the solution as accepted answer.

Comment: Happy to hear that.